# Should World of Warcraft Questions Be Closed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I think we should close World of Warcraft questions and direct them to [Epic Advice](http://www.epicadvice.com/). I would assume most WoW questions would have already been answered or would receive better responses at [Epic Advice](http://www.epicadvice.com/).

Comment: Epic advice is currently a dead site, "epicadvice.com" leads to nothing. Which would make this question obsolete.

Answer (score 16):

But ... is World of Warcraft not a video game?

Yes, players may be better served at Epic Advice, but that said, I don't see why we would need to make a rule against the content.

Put another way: **most** gaming questions can be answered on some other site out there, whether a game-specific site (such as [The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/) or [CivFanatics](http://www.civfanatics.com/)) or a more general one (such as [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/)). The logic used to shut down questions on WoW could easily apply to any game where there is a highly-devoted following with its own web presence.

Thus, I'd say not a great idea.

Comment: Then whats the point of Epic Advice? Might as well have them come join us or vice versa. Seems like duplicate content to me.

Comment: Is there any reason duplicate content on the web is inherently a *bad* thing?

Comment: there are no rules about SE sites overlapping or not overlapping.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason that we cannot coexist with another site peacefully. For example, back on Stack Overflow, we get questions about SharePoint. There is also a SharePoint Overflow, which specifically is about all kinds of SharePoint stuff. We don't automatically close SharePoint things back at Stack Overflow just because it overlaps with another site.

Certainly, there might be better answerers at EpicAdvice. But we also are gamers, some who probably play WoW, so we should have the capacity to answer questions that end up here.

Answer (score 5):

Although Epic Advice has an obvious appeal, I would like to bring up a problem with making gaming.se subordinate and closing all WoW questions / forwarding all WoW questions to Epic Advice.

Epic Advice is considered NSFW: as in it will be blocked by a lot of daytime/work content filters that stackexchange isn't. I dont know if this is entirely relevant, but as soon as a site is blocked it will stangle a certain amount of the community.

Also, for me the crux is this: do we want a significant amount of community (who have knowledge about games other than WoW) to go to another site and not contribute here? (why manage your presence on 2 BBs when it could be just one?)

Answer (score 3):

I can't see why we should close them. I think that a lot of people play WoW and have a lot of knowledge that they want to share, so we should foster them to join our community,

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, we should be working together with Epic Advice (preferably on the SE 2.0 engine) where Epic Advice is ***The One Resource*** for anything WoW.

The reason behind this, is that the WoW community is large enough to sustain a seperate site, and prevents gaming to be over-flooded with WoW questions. (we're a gaming site, covering console, PC and arcade, and not a 75% WoW site, doing the other things as a side job.)

Also, MMO games, usually have to deal with changing content, where most released games don't have that problem.

I would like to see a message similar to this in the FAQ

> If you have a question about World of Warcraft, we have a seperate dedicated site for you, over at [Epic Advice](http://www.epicadvice.com/)

Comment: Depending on how this is executed, it might not be a bad idea, I would suggest posting this on [What should go in our FAQ](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/226/what-should-our-faq-contain) for better review (not the least of which is because this question has sufficient downvotes to not appear on the front page anymore).

Answer (score -5):

I agree with [alexanderpas](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244/should-world-of-warcraft-questions-be-closed/254#254), but I'd be more precise.
When someone ask a question about World of Warcraft on this site, as soon as he enters the WoW tag on this site, Epic Advice should be suggested and also searched for similar questions.

Questions should be crossposted on Epic Advice, too.

I also think questions on Epic Advice should not be crossposted here.

Comment: Cross-posting isn't really a good idea. Either ask here or there, not on both places.